# Should I travel to Morocco alone as a young female?

Tags: morocco, solo-travel, female-travellers

I've already booked a flight for a one-week long winter holiday to Morocco. Due to a great change of circumstances (=breakup), my partner won't accompany me on the trip. I have never been to Morocco, is it safe to stay and possibly travel there alone as a young female? Are there any safety considerations I'm supposed to take? Marrakesh and Agadir are the cities I planned to visit before, using the public transport between the cities.

Comment: A small tip: Stay away from any local that tries to be nice or offer help... And you will be fine..

Comment: I previously thought that people in Morocco would be better for women than the gulf states, but a woman I talked to said the opposite.

Comment: @Andrew: I can confirm this!

Answer (score 10):

All of the city centres in Morocco's metropolitan cities are basically as safe as any other city. Tangier, for example, has cleaned up its act a lot. Most safety tips are 'generic' non-gender specific, like stay alert when using an ATM or walking on poorly lit streets after dark.

A few tips pertinent to women, however, are...

**Train and bus travel** -

> Traveling by train or long-distance bus is generally considered safe,
>   though it pays to keep one eye on your luggage at each stop. Women
>   travelers should look for seats close to those occupied by Moroccan
>   women. The country’s taxis— both petit and grand—are considered
>   generally crime free, but may be poorly maintained and driven
>   recklessly (a request of “beshwïya” [“slowly”] may or may not be
>   heeded). Traveling on a crowded city bus can be unsafe.

**Harassment** -

> Encountering unwanted attention from Moroccan men is unfortunately a
>   possibility for female travelers. The relative lack of social
>   interaction between the sexes in Morocco results in men having little
>   exposure to women other than their immediate family. They often see
>   Western women as not being bound by Morocco’s social restrictions, and
>   perhaps have a not-so respectful assumption of them via easily
>   accessible Internet pornography. This assumption of availability
>   emboldens the Moroccan male to make advances on female travelers that
>   they would never attempt with Moroccan women. This generally takes the
>   form of catcalls and straight-up come-ons. Blonde women may be singled
>   out, and women traveling alone generally receive more attention than
>   most. Women on the receiving end of nonphysical sexual harassment
>   should do what Moroccan women do: Ignore it. Showing confidence and
>   self assurance also seems to deter a lot of would-be Romeos.

**Dressing modestly** —

> a long skirt and loose, long-sleeve shirt—can help. Having said that,
>   I’ve seen Western women wearing jellabahs (the traditional robe worn
>   by local women) on the receiving end of lewd comments.

**A generic tip on the grands taxis** -

> There are some pertinent safety concerns attached to traveling in
>   grands taxis. Many drivers are under pressure to work long hours, and
>   falling asleep at the wheel is a definite possibility on night drives,
>   so it’s best to travel by day. Within that busy day, a driver is
>   trying to fit in as many journeys as possible, and will often drive as
>   if there is no one else on the road. Overtaking on blind corners is
>   common on many grand taxi journeys. Added to this is the lack of
>   available seat belts, because it’s either too cramped within the
>   vehicle or there quite simply aren’t any. Needless to say, when
>   chartering a grand taxi, stress on the driver your expectations toward
>   his driving.

**Hustlers, Faux Guides, Pickpockets, etc** - MeNoTalk's comment above applies. If someone is trying to distract you, go into hyper-alert mode. This holds true for both men and women.

*Frommer's Morocco* (ISBN 978-0-470-18403-5) has these and several other valuable tips.  It's recommended. Citations from [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OfcnGQxF42wC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=The%20relative%20lack%20of%20social%20interaction%20between%20the%20sexes%20in%20Morocco&source=bl&ots=I1LbX0IMFr&sig=SJhNtb7n6A0lh8YL6o3kq-Ch7Vc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-cSkVJK4McWsUcmGgrgL&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20relative%20lack%20of%20social%20interaction%20between%20the%20sexes%20in%20Morocco&f=false)